# Jersey 2.22: When should I close the Client instance?

Tags: java, jersey, client

In my MVC web application, my services rely on the `Client` instance to create HTTP requests to a web service. According to the Jersey documentation, it is quite expensive to initialize and destroy client objects so what I did was I just created a singleton `Client` instance:

`private static final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();`

My question is, when should I close this instance? Because it seems like the only time I wouldn't be using the `Client` is when the application terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define it as a `Singleton` in some fashion then you don't really need to - it lives and dies with your application. Sometimes, you might define a Client instance for a specific short- or medium-term need (say you have an application which speaks to multiple remote endpoints which change during the lifetime of the application). In those cases it would be best to explicitly close the Client 'at some point' to make it clear that it's not intended for reuse. The tricky part might be defining what 'at some point' really means.